# Cant make a successful post using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to send some data to my mongo database. I can make a successful post inside of Postman. But when it comes to axios it just won't work.
Could someone please tell me why that is?
Please notice that I have added the the localhost adress inside the proxy in my packagejson. So the full adress is used.
But I always get a 404 not found.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.value)
    this.postToMongoDB()
    this.setState({ value: '' })
  }

  postToMongoDB = () => {
    const newUser = {
      room: 'general',
      username: this.state.value,
      message: 'Why cant I send this?'
    }

    axios
      .post('/members/message', newUser)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange= 
            {this.onChange} />
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Some people have said that I should have the same port in my backend as my front-end react.
But if I do then this happens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you're able to connect to Axios ... but Axios is returning 404: not found.  Correct?

Comment: Axios is connected, imported the way it should if that is what you mean?

Comment: do you have baseUrl setup for the axios ? Another question is can you directly send to the mongo ? Don't you need a BE server e.g node for the api request ?

Looking at your edit, the postman request is port 3000 and the request from react is 3001

Comment: In the console, it appears that it is trying with localhost:3001 when in postman you are using localhost:3000

Comment: The backend is connected to port 3000, but react is connected to port 3001.
In another app that works I have the backend port connected to 1337 and the react port is 3000. 
So that surely can't be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000', // maybe you wanna store this in env file for different environment
});

export default instance
```

You create an instance and use this instance in your axios fetch.

```
// In your react js
import axios from "./axiosInstance";

...
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work, all I did was to restart the react server after I changed the package.json proxy manually, now it works. Seems like it doesn't update automatically if you change in the package.json like it does in all other instances.

Comment: the proxy thing works only in development/localhost. You better do it the way I mentioned which is ideal practise.